# Remove value from JSON if the end date matches with today's date

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have these two tables named Product_details and Pricing table.

Product_details table:

[image: Product_details table]

Pricing table:

[image: Pricing table]

I want to update the product_Details table if the start date and end date match with today's date and current time.
So, if the start_Date matches with the current date and time, it will update the product_Details table to offer price or promotional price depending on the id that's the inner query returning.
If the end_Date matches with the current date and time, it will delete the offer price or promotional price depending on the id that's the inner query returning.
The code I wrote is as follows.

-- This code works appropriately, which updates the product_details table and inserts offer/promotional prices if the start_Date matches with today's date and current time.

```
> UPDATE product_Details 
            SET price_and_price_Type =
> price_and_price_Type || 
>               ( pps.details::jsonb )          FROM ( 
>               select id, price_Details as details 
>               from pricing 
>               where to_char(start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') = to_char(now(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
>               group by id, details
>               ) as pps            where product_Details.id = "pps".id ;
```

-- this is the code that doesn't work. I wrote to delete the jsonB value, which is the offer or promotional price previously updated depending on the id.

```
UPDATE product_Details 
            SET price_and_price_Type = price_and_price_Type -
                ( pps.details::jsonb )
            FROM ( 
                select id, price_Details as details 
                from pricing 
                where to_char(end_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') = to_char(now(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
                group by id, details
                ) as pps 
            where product_Details.id = "pps".id ;
```

The error raises:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb - jsonb
LINE 2:    SET price_and_price_Type = price_and_price_Type -
                                                           ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: **Do not use images for textual information**. Copy and paste the table definitions as text into your question.

Comment: 1) Why the `to_char()` transforms? Just compare the timestamps directly. 2) The error message is telling you the problem you can't subtract `jsonb` records. You need to pull the price values out of the `jsonb` and subtract them. 3) You could make your life simpler by pulling the information of `jsonb`(price_details) and into `price_type` and and `price_val` columns.  Nesting data gets complicated in a hurry.